# Month Calculate every 28 Days

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

is there any way in Oracle that My month start after every 28 days 
Example 
24-dec- 2015  to  20-jan-16 ( we mention Dec 2015) 
21-jan-16 to 17-feb-16 (we mention Jan 16)

Comment: Is there any way to do what? For the system to automatically do this? **NO** , but you can build your own table containing these ranges of dates.

Comment: Add days to the dates  `ModifiedDate := OriginalDate + interval '28' day;`

Comment: You can also generate them on the fly if you have a base date to start from, but if you need to do this a lot then a look-up table is probably better.

Comment: Are you using something like International Fixed Calendar but not from  January 1?

Comment: yes We have 13 Months not 12 month

Answer (score 0):

```
select rownum as month_number
      ,day1 + (rownum-1) * 28 as gregorian_month_start
      ,day1 + rownum * 28 - 1 as gregorian_month_end
from   (select date'2015-12-24' day1
        from dual connect by level <= 13);

1   24/DEC/2015 20/JAN/2016
2   21/JAN/2016 17/FEB/2016
3   18/FEB/2016 16/MAR/2016
4   17/MAR/2016 13/APR/2016
5   14/APR/2016 11/MAY/2016
6   12/MAY/2016 08/JUN/2016
7   09/JUN/2016 06/JUL/2016
8   07/JUL/2016 03/AUG/2016
9   04/AUG/2016 31/AUG/2016
10  01/SEP/2016 28/SEP/2016
11  29/SEP/2016 26/OCT/2016
12  27/OCT/2016 23/NOV/2016
13  24/NOV/2016 21/DEC/2016
```

Note: this doesn't handle the 365th day for normal years, or 366th day for leap years. You would need to specify which month these should be added to.